# Tomcat DataSource plain text password viewable in jconsole when omitting factory argument

Tags: java, tomcat

We have several Tomcat installations on several servers. I found out that on some, if I connect with jconsole, I can view the data source password in plain text. On others it displays *“Password not available as DataSource/JMX operation.”* instead.

I have noticed that the cause of this is that the PW is displayed in plain text when I omit the `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` argument in the **context.xml** file.

I have no idea what this argument does and I can't figure it out by reading the documentation. Can someone please explain what that argument does and why it causes the password to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Links:

*When the attribute factory="org.apache.naming.factory.DataSourceLinkFactory" the resource link can be used with two additional attributes to allow a shared data source to be used with different credentials. When these two additional attributes are used in combination with the javax.sql.DataSource type, different contexts can share a global data source with different credentials. Under the hood, what happens is that a call to getConnection() is simply translated to a call getConnection(username, password) on the global data source. This is an easy way to get code to be transparent to what schemas are being used, yet be able to control connections (or pools) in the global configuration.*

It is also mentioned as required in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html